# Questions about the factoextra package in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

I am performing PCA on some data and I am using the `factoextra` package from CRAN. This package give the user many options to create graphs about PCA on your data. However, I have a few questions about some of the examples they give on this [page here](http://www.sthda.com/english/rpkgs/factoextra/) and [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/rpkgs/factoextra/reference/fviz_pca.html).

1. In the third hyperlink it states: Note that, fviz_pca_xxx() functions are wrapper arround the core function fviz(), whih is also a wrapper arround the function ggscatter() [in ggpubr]. Therfore, further arguments, to be passed to the function fviz() and ggscatter(), can be specified in fviz_pca_ind() and fviz_pca_var(). I have tried to add other `ggplot` parameters like `title('Title')` but I receive a warning message of invalid graphics state. How would I add base ggplot graphs to manipulate my `fviz_pca_ind` graph?

Code:

```
library(factoextra)
data(iris)
res.pca <- prcomp(iris[, -5],  scale = TRUE)
fviz_pca_ind(res.pca,
             geom="text",
             #col.var="contrib",
             col.ind = "dodgerblue2",
             repel = FALSE)+     # Avoid text overlapping
 title('Principal Component Analysis')+
 theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA),
    plot.margin = unit(c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1), "cm"),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 14, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 1),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA)
  )
```

2. My data is unlabelled, unlike the `iris` database. Can someone explain coloring either the variables or individuals on their contribution? But my question is, contribution to what? How are we coloring the individuals on contribution?

Comment: change `title` to `ggtitle` like `ggtitle('Principal Component Analysis')`

Comment: What about adding themes? Also any idea on number 2?

Comment: I guess you want to predict the species, so you could color on species ? in the general case in what ever you want to predict..

Comment: If your data points are unlabelled, you will need to classify them first. PCA and related methods are not the method of choice. You could try e.g. hierarchical clustering or k-means clustering, for example.

Comment: I know PCA does not classify the points, hence my reason for clustering in the first place. But did not know what the contribution aspect of the individuals/variables meant.